# Convert object to Map<String, String> in java

Tags: java, dictionary

Please suggest how to convert an Object to `Map<String, String>` in java. 
Tried org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap(object).
This is returning `Map<String, Object only`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to convert an object( which is basically a POJO ) to a Map<String,String>

Comment: Just convert the map to a `Map<String,String>` afterwards using `toString()` on the values.

Comment: Why don't you write your own version of Factory Class to typecast to your desired type. You can delegate the maximum job of this new API of yours to supportive API like... PropertyUtils.describe(object) ...

Comment: I also had similar requirement and ended up written few lines of code. Check my answer below, how can we convert "Object[][] obj" to Map<String, String> in Java.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Iterate over the `Map<String, Object>` and use `newMap.put(key, value.toString());` to fill a new `Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 2):

How about [PropertyUtils.describe(object)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#describe(java.lang.Object)) though it works only for Java Beans (meaning Java Objects that implement getters)

Comment: This is also returning `Map<String, Object`. I need `Map<String, String>`

Comment: then loop on the map and put the entries in a new map doing `value.toString()`.  do you need the code for that?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to convert "Object[][] obj" to Map. In that case here is my solution:

```
public static Map<String, String> convert2DArrayObjectToMap(Object[][] object)
{
    Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

    if (object != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
        {
            if (object[i] != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < object[i].length; j++)
                {
                    map.putAll((TreeMap<String, String>) object[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: This looks good. I suggest using map() with optional index parameter e.g. ```arr.map((anotherArr, i) => {
    anotherArr.map((val, j) => {
        console.log(i, j);
    })
})``` (pardon the lack of returns)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to convert a Java object into a Map easily.

1 - Get Jackson (pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

2 - Convert Object to Map:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<String> skills;

  // getters setters
}



import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

public class ObjectToMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Student obj = new Student();
        obj.setName("Test");
        obj.setAge(34);
        obj.setSkills(Arrays.asList("java","node"));

        // object -> Map
        Map<String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
        System.out.println(map);

    }

}
```

Output:

```
{name=Test, age=34, skills=[java, node]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for you not making it manually? It's not that much of a hassle, and you can implement it easily, something like this.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
//obj represents any object you wanna put inside the map
String key = "your key";
map.put(key, obj.toString());
```

if the object you want to turn into a map is an iterable object such as a list you can try something like this.

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Integer i = 0;
for (Object s:list) {
    map.put(String.valueOf(i), s.toString());
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This seems not an answer to the OP.. He's asking to convert an object to a map, not to insert that object in a map with random keys.

Comment: That's not the answer of initial question. Review the question again.